# Are there any advantage sorting on indexed fields

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I want to perform a sort operation on some field. Is it advantageous making an index on that field. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `age`=33 ORDER BY `name`
```

In this query, I know that having an index on age is helpful, but would it be better if I maintain an index for name. Would there be a performance gain by indexing it. And the `ORDER BY` operation is frequently needed for other queries as well.

Comment: Are there many users of age 33? A separate, additional index on "name" is probably not too useful, but maybe index (age, name).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An index on `name` alone would not be likely to help significantly with this query, but an index on `(age, name)` would.

While it's not entirely accurate, it's often instructive to think of an index as a list of rows sorted by the keys in the index (e.g, sorted by `age` first, then by `name`). In the case of your sample query, all the rows with `age=33` would naturally come out of the composite index sorted by name, saving you from doing a separate sort. Having a separate index for `name` wouldn't help the same way.

Comment: Actually for other queries, I would be would needing results to be sorted by just name, and there won't be necessarily age field in the where clause

Comment: +1. And if there are only a few records left after the WHERE clause, it won't make much difference either.

Comment: @SushantGupta: Well, you have to build indexes to match the queries you have. Maybe a different one for each. Otherwise the index will not be very effective. In particular, an index that "somehow" covers all queries, but none of them really well, is not a good index.

Comment: Ok, but for other queries I need sorting but there won't be a where clause with age as its field

Comment: While also not entirely accurate, it helps to think that every query (or rather: every table used in a query) can use *only one* index. For your example, an index on "age" is much better than one on "name", and (age, name) should trump both (while being relatively useless when you don't filter by age).

Comment: Can someone please explain what should I do if for other queries I DON'T use age as the field and HAVE to do ordering my results by name

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12723/discussion-between-sushant-gupta-and-thilo)

Comment: @SushantGupta: Depends on the query. Also: try different indexes and measure it.

Comment: There's no single index that'd work for all situations. You will have to tune your indices for the queries that matter most.